Vue.js form with v-if not hidden when showFormBoolena is set to false
I have  parentform with a child form that allows to add games.
The childform has option to edit games, and the grandchildform has option to add cards to the game, using a Imageupload component.
The idea is that admin can add cards using the cardform, whic is opened by clicking: add card, and which must close when card is added.
Then the list of existing must be refreshed ( does not woreither, ...)
When I add a card to a game, and this is succesfull I set ShowCardForm=false, but this is not changed in the devtools VUE window.
While console shows that "ShowCardForm must be false now: false", as expected from the code.
I have been messing around for hours now, can anyone see what I am missing? (ChatGPT was a great help either...)
Here is part of the script:
  alert('Card added/updated successfully');
           
            this.showCardForm = false;
            console.log('ShowCardForm must be false now:', this.showCardForm);

            this.resetForm(); 

Can anyone see how I can solve this?
Here is the whole script:
GameAdmin:
<template>
<Navibar ></Navibar> 


<div class ="custom-container" >
    <br>
    <br>
    <div v-if="!showGameForm"  class="text-center">
        
        
        <h2>Game-beheer </h2>
        <button  @click="toggleShowGameForm" class="btn btn-info m-1">Nieuw spel maken</button>
    </div>
     <div class="card text-center card-bg" v-if="showGameForm">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form  class="mb-3"   > 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label><h4> Gamenaam: </h4></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="naam" v-model="game.naam">
                    </div>
                </div>
                    
    
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label><h4> Stel de status in: </h4></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                        <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="game_status" id="closed" v-model="game.game_status" value="closed">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="closed"> Niet actief </label>
                        <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="game_status" id="open" v-model="game.game_status" value='open' checked="checked">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="open"> Kaarten maken </label>
                        <input class="btn-check" type="radio" name="game_status" id="actief" v-model="game.game_status" value="actief">
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="actief"> Actief </label>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    
                    
                </div>
                <br><br>

                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <button @click="toggleShowGameForm" class="btn btn-info">Terug</button>
                    <button @click= "addgame" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>

                <ManageCards :key = "currentGame.id" v-if="currentGame && Object.keys(currentGame).length"></ManageCards>
            
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div v-if="!gamesExist">
        Er zijn nog geen games gemaakt.
        </div>
    <div v-if="!showGameForm && gamesExist">  <!-- Laat lijst met spellen zien als er geen editscherm van een bepaald spel open staat -->
        <div class="card text-center card-bg mt-2" v-for="game in games.slice().reverse()" v-bind:key="game.id" >   
            <div class="card-body m-2">
                <h5 class="card-title"> Gamenaam: {{game.naam}}   </h5>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <!-- <li class="list-group-item">Modus: {{game.game_mode}}</li> -->
                    <li class="list-group-item">Status:  {{game.game_status}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Pin: {{game.pin}}</li>
                </ul>
            

                    
                <button @click="deletegame(game.id)" class="btn btn-danger m-1" style="width:100px;color:white">  Delete  </button>
                <button @click="toggleShowGameForm(); editgame(game)" class="btn btn-warning m-1" style="width:100px;color:black">  Edit  </button>
                <button @click="setCurrentGame(game.pin)" class="btn btn-warning m-1" style="width:100px;color:black">  Run  {{game.pin}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {

    mounted() {
        console.log('component mounted');
        this.$store.commit('SET_CURRENT_GAME', {}); // Ensure currentGame is initialized as an empty object
        this.getGames();
    },
      computed: {
        ...mapState([
        'games' , 'token','currentGame'
        ]),
        gamesExist() {
        return this.games && this.games.length > 0;
        }, 
    },
    data() {
        return{
           // games:[],
            game:{
                id:'',
                naam:'',
                game_mode:'',
                game_status:'',
                pin: 0,
            },
            game_id:'',
            edit:false,
            selected:'',
            showGameForm: false,
            currentGameError:false,
            checked:false,
            
        }

    },
    created(){
        //this.fetchgames();
          
    },
  
    methods: {

        ...mapActions([  'getGames', 'addGame',  'retrieveGameByPin' ]),

        toggleShowGameForm(){
            this.$store.commit('SET_CURRENT_GAME',{});
            this.game.naam='naam';
            this.game.game_mode='open';
            this.game.game_status='open';
            this.game.pin='0';
            this.showGameForm = !this.showGameForm;
        },

     
        async setCurrentGame(pin){
            console.log("ik krijg deze pin door:"+ pin);
           await this.retrieveGameByPin(pin)
            .then(res =>  {
                console.log('gelukt met pin' + pin)   // als status 200, dan resolvet de promise uit de action, and komen we hier uit
                console.log("retrievegamebypin result == " + JSON.stringify(res));
            })  
            .catch(err => {
                //this.currentGameError = true;
                console.error(err);
            });
      
        },

        // DELETE GAME WERKT NOG NIET, KAN PAS ALS ALLE CARDS OOK VERWIJDERD ZIJN..
        deletegame(id){
            if(confirm('Are you sure?')){
               const formData = new FormData();
               formData.append('_method', 'DELETE');  // axios setting
               const config = {
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer `+ this.token} 
                };
                axios.post(`../api/games/${id}`,
                    formData,
                    config
                )
                //.then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    // De game is verwijderd, nu vernieuw de lijst met games
                    this.getGames()
                     .then(res => { 
                        console.log(res);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }

        },
        addgame(){
            // de informatie voor de game staat inthis.$game, nu omzetten naar FormData om file toe te voegen aan de request zodat api die kan opslaan, api gaat ook naam bedenken voor de game.
            //  via fetchgames() komt die naam dadelijk terug in game.picture
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('naam',this.game.naam);
            formData.append('game_mode',this.game.game_mode);
            formData.append('game_status',this.game.game_status);
            //formData.append('pin',this.game.pin); //this.game.pin);
            //formData.append('user_id', 11); //this.game.user_id); dit wordt aan de hand van de api-token op de server ingevuld
         

            if(this.edit === false){
                //add
                console.log("adding" +  formData);
                this.addGame(formData)
                .then(data => {
                    this.game.naam='';
                    this.game.game_mode='';
                    this.game.game_status='';
                    this.game.pin='';
                   // this.game.user_id='';   dit wordt aan de hand van de api-token op de server ingevuld
                    this.showGameForm=false;
                    //alert('game added');
                    this.getGames()
                    .then(res => { 
                        console.log(res);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            } else{
                //update
                console.log("updating");
                formData.append('_method', 'PUT');  // axios setting
                const config = {
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` }
                };
                axios.post(`../api/games/${this.game.id}`,
                    formData, 
                    config
                )
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                .then(data => {
                    this.game.naam='';
                    this.game.game_mode='';
                    this.game.game_status='';
                    alert('game updated_admin.vue');
                        this.getGames();
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        },
        editgame(game){
            this.currentGame = this.retrieveGameByPin(game.pin);
            this.edit=true;
            this.game.id=game.id;
            this.game.game_id=game.id;
            this.game.naam=game.naam;
            this.game.game_mode=game.game_mode;
            this.game.game_status=game.game_status;
            this.game.pin=game.pin;
        },

    }
}
</script>

ManageCards:
<template>
    <div class="custom-container" v-if="currentGame.id != undefined">
      <!-- Container wordt alleen weergegeven als er een currentGame is -->
      <div class="text-center">
        <br><br>
        <!-- Weergeven van de naam van het huidige spel -->
        <h1>{{ currentGame.naam }}</h1>
        <!-- Knop om het formulier voor het maken van een nieuwe kaart te tonen/verbergen -->
        <button type="button" @click="toggleShowCardForm" class="btn btn-info m-1">Nieuwe kaart maken</button>
  
        <!-- Formulier voor het maken/bewerken van een kaart -->
        <div class="card text-center card-bg" v-if="showCardForm">
          <h5 class="card-header">Kaart</h5>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form class="mb-3" >
              <div class="form-group">
                <!-- Beschrijving van de kaart -->
                <h4>{{ card.description }}</h4>
                <!-- Tekstveld voor het bewerken van de beschrijving -->
                <textarea class="form-control" :placeholder="card.description" v-model="card.description"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div>
                <!-- Voorbeeldweergave van de afbeelding van de kaart -->
                <img v-if="card.picture" class="img-circle" style="width:150px" :src="card.picture"/>
              </div>
              <div id="preview">
                <h4> Preview</h4>
                <!-- Component voor het uploaden van afbeeldingen -->
                <ImageUpload ref="imageUpload" :imgUrl="url" @newPicture="updatePicture"></ImageUpload>
              </div>
              <br>
              <!-- Knop om de kaart op te slaan -->
              <button @click="addCard();" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="color:white">Save</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <!-- Lijst van kaarten -->
      <div v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
        <div class="card text-center card-bg mt-2">
          <div class="card-body mb-2" style="width: 100%">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <!-- Beschrijving van de kaart -->
                <h3>{{ card.description }}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <!-- Afbeelding van de kaart -->
                <img class="img-circle" style="width:150px" :src="card.picture" alt="Card Image">
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <br>
                <!-- Knoppen voor het verwijderen en bewerken van de kaart -->
                <span @click="deleteCard(card.id)"><i class="bi bi-trash m-1"></i></span>
                <span @click="editCard(card)"><i class="bi bi-pencil m-1"></i></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import ImageUpload from './ImageUpload.vue';
  
  export default {
    components: {
      ImageUpload, // Component voor het uploaden van afbeeldingen
    },

    watch: {
        showCardForm(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log(`showCardForm changed from ${oldVal} to ${newVal}`);
        }
    },

    data() {
      return {
        card: {
          id: '', // ID van de kaart
          title: 'title', // Titel van de kaart
          description: 'naam', // Beschrijving van de kaart
          picture: '', // Afbeelding van de kaart
        },
        edit: false, // Boolean om te checken of we een kaart aan het bewerken zijn
        selectedFile: '', // Bestand geselecteerd voor uploaden
        showCardForm: false, // Boolean om het formulier te tonen/verbergen
        url: '', // URL van de geüploade afbeelding
        successMessage: '', // Bericht voor succesvolle bewerkingen
      };
    },

    computed: {
      ...mapState(['cards', 'currentGame', 'token']), // Vuex state voor kaarten, huidig spel en token
    },
    async mounted() {
      // Wanneer de component wordt geladen
      try {
        await this.getCards(this.currentGame.id); // Haal de kaarten op voor het huidige spel
        console.log('component mounted');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during mounted hook:', error);
      }
    },

    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['getCards']), // Vuex acties voor het ophalen van kaarten
      toggleShowCardForm() {
        this.showCardForm = !this.showCardForm; // Toon/verberg het formulier
        this.url = ''; // Reset de url wanneer het formulier wordt weergegeven of verborgen
        this.getCards(this.currentGame.id); // Haal opnieuw de kaarten op
      },
      async deleteCard(id) {
        // Verwijder een kaart
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('_method', 'DELETE'); // Methode voor het verwijderen instellen
          const config = {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` }, // Configuratie voor de aanvraag met token
          };
  
          try {
            await axios.post(`../api/cards/${id}`, formData, config); // Verwijder kaart
            alert('Card removed');
            await this.getCards(this.currentGame.id); // Haal opnieuw de kaarten op
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error deleting card:', error);
          }
        }
      },
      async addCard() {
        // Voeg een nieuwe kaart toe of werk een bestaande kaart bij
        try {
          await this.$refs.imageUpload.setImage(); // Zet de imageUrl naar de picture en sla de picture of als file
  
          if (!this.selectedFile) {
            alert('Please select an image file');
            return;
          }
  
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('title', this.card.title); // Voeg de titel toe aan formData
          formData.append('description', this.card.description); // Voeg de beschrijving toe aan formData
          formData.append('imagefile', this.selectedFile); // Voeg de afbeelding toe aan formData
          formData.append('game_id', this.currentGame.id); // Voeg het spel-ID toe aan formData
  
          let response;
          if (!this.edit) {
            // Nieuwe kaart toevoegen
            response = await fetch(`api/cards`, {
              method: 'POST',
              body: formData,
            }).then(response => response.json());
          } else {
            // Bestaande kaart bijwerken
            formData.append('_method', 'PUT');
            const config = {
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` },
            };
            response = await axios.post(`../api/cards/${this.card.id}`, formData, config).then(res => res.data);
          }
  
          if (response && response.id) {
          
          
            alert('Card added/updated successfully');
           
            this.showCardForm = false;
            console.log('ShwoCardForm must be false now:', this.showCardForm);

            this.resetForm();
            
           
          } else {
            alert('Failed to add/update card');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error updating card:', error);
          alert('An error occurred while adding/updating the card');
        }
      },
      editCard(card) {
        // Zet de huidige kaart voor bewerking
        window.scrollTo(0, 0); // Scroll naar boven
        this.edit = true; // Zet edit mode aan
        this.showCardForm = true; // Toon het formulier
        this.card = { ...card }; // Kopieer de kaartgegevens
      },
      updatePicture(imageData) {
        // Werk de afbeelding bij
        this.selectedFile = imageData.file; // Zet het geselecteerde bestand
        this.card.picture = imageData.picture; // Zet de afbeelding URL
      },
      resetForm() {
        // Reset het formulier
        this.card = {
          id: '',
          title: '',
          description: '',
          picture: '',
        };
        this.url = ''; // Reset de URL
        this.edit = false; // Zet edit mode uit
      },
    },
  };
  </script>
  


and IMageUpload:
<template>
    <div class="Image-Upload-wrapper Image-upload"> 
        <div>
                <input type="file" v-on:change="onFileChange" ref="fileUpload" id="file_picture_input">
                <label for ="file_picture_input" class="upload_picture_button"> Kies afbeelding</label>
        </div>
       

       <div id="croppie"> </div>     

       <div class="upload-wrapper">
            <!-- type="button"" anders vervest de knop de hele pagina " -->  
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" v-on:click="setImage"> SetImage!  </button>-->
        </div>   
 
    </div>
</template>



<script>
//  uitleg over Croppie::https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvNozA8M1HM
import Croppie from 'croppie';

export default {
    props:[
        'imgUrl'
    ],
    emits:['newPicture'
    ],
    mounted(){
              this.setUpCroppie()
    },
    data(){
        return{
           croppie:null,
           croppieImage:'',
           selectedFile:'',
           picture:'',
           url:this.imgUrl || '',
        }
    },
    //Zorg ervoor dat imgUrl updates correct worden doorgegeven aan Croppie.
    watch: {
        imgUrl(newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                this.url = newVal;
                this.croppie.bind({ url: newVal });
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        setUpCroppie(){
           let el = document.getElementById('croppie');
           this.croppie = new Croppie(el, {
               viewport:{width:200,height:200,type:'circle'},
               boundary:{ width:220,height:220},
               showZoomer:true,
               enableOrientation: true
           });
           this.croppie.bind({       
               url:this.url
           })
           .catch(error => console.error('Error binding croppie with url:', error));
        },
        setImage(){
            return this.croppie.result({
                type:'canvas',
                size:'viewport'
            })
            .then(blob =>fetch(blob))
            .then(res => {return res.arrayBuffer();})
            .then(buf => {return new File([buf], this.croppieImage.name, {type:'image/png'});})
            .then(file => { 
                this.croppieImage = file;
                this.picture = URL.createObjectURL(this.croppieImage);
                const imageData={
                    picture:this.picture, 
                    file: this.croppieImage
                };
                console.log("klaar voor emit...?");
                this.$emit('newPicture', imageData);
                this.url='';
            })
            .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error setting image:", error);
            });
        },
        onFileChange(e){ 
            if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
                this.selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
                console.log("gekozen file is: " + this.selectedFile.name);
                this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.selectedFile);
                this.croppie.bind({
                    url: this.url
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error binding croppie with file url:', error));
             } else {
            // Geen afbeelding geselecteerd, instellen op een standaardwaarde (bijv. een lege string)
            this.selectedFile = null;
            this.url = '';
            }
        },
        reset() {
            this.selectedFile = null;
            this.picture = '';
            this.url = '';
            this.croppie.bind({
                url: ''
            }).catch(error => console.error('Error binding croppie with reset url:', error));
        }
    },
  
}
</script>


It's unclear what's the problem. You state " this is not changed in the devtools VUE window" but not how it really behaves. Please, provide a way to reproduce. The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. There are several pages of code, it's not minimal and needs to be debugged. Basically if showCardForm is reactive (it is) and it's changed (it is), and this.showCardForm is accessed in the correct context (it is), the changes should be displayed in  v-if="!showGameForm", there's no other way around, unless there are errors during component render
